# why dynamic integer right align in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

What I am trying to do below in my code is just print all the types of number formats available in right aligned manner.

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        width = len(format(i, 'b'))
        print("{0:d} {0:o} {0:x} {0:{w}b}".format(i, w=len(format(i, 'b'))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)

Input:
4
Expected Output:
1 1 1   1
2 2 2  10
3 3 3  11
4 4 4 100

But actual output:
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 10
3 3 3 11
4 4 4 100
```

The above code works fine if I give a static value in-place of 'w' but if I pass dynamic changing value it is not working as expected. What am I missing here

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where do you see anything different with a static width spec ?

Comment: See https://pyformat.info for a good reference on this subject

Comment: Also, you don't need to compute width with each iteration. Place it above the loop

Comment: What I was trying to say is if I replace 'w' with a static value say for e.g '2' I can see my output is proper for all the 2 digit values. Now that your suggestion is working fine for me can you just explain how is it working as expected when width is placed outside loop and was not working when I was dynamically calculating the width.

Comment: You were computing the field width to be the width of `i`, which is the same as not using a field width at all, instead of `number` which is what you meant to do.

Comment: This is basically a typo on your part, so unless you reeeeealy think it will be useful to someone in the future, I recommend deleting the question.